# What header to include to use UTType in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following code snippet:

```
    NSString* filt = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:allowedExtensions[i].c_str()];
    UTType *type = [UTType typeWithIdentifier:filt];
```

I get the error `'Receiver 'UTType' for class message is a forward declaration'`. If I'm understanding this right this means that UTType is not included properly. What file do I need to include to have it declared properly? I'm using Cocoa. I could find zero information about this through Google. I'm using Xcode 13. I'm developing for MacOS.

Stuff listed here didn't help: [receiver type *** for instance message is a forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815200/receiver-type-for-instance-message-is-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype?language=objc

Comment: I found the documentation, where does this tell me which header to include?

Comment: Where it says the framework name. That tells you what module to import.

Comment: ahhh, okay i didnt get that! thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UTType comes from a [UniformTypeIdentifiers framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype?language=objc)

`@import UniformTypeIdentifiers;`

or

`#import <UniformTypeIdentifiers/UniformTypeIdentifiers.h>`

both are equivalent.